# changing a string in a function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

if I have this kind of function: str1= NULL in the begining

```
 Result dosomething(char* str1, char* str){
    str1=malloc(strlen(str2)+1); //followed by NULL check
    strcpy(str1, str2);
    .
    .
 return something
```

then I use this function in some other function:

```
 char* output="hello";
 char* input=NULL;
 result=dosomething(input,output);
```

for some reason input remains NULL after using "dosomething" function, although if I use printf right after the strcpy, I can see that str1 did change to "hello". am I doing something wrong with the char* here when passing them to other function?

Comment: In C, function arguments are passed by value. That is, they are copied. Now re-think what you want your code to do, what it does, and consider the *why* (and search for a duplicate, because there are plenty of them).

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a pointer to the string you want to change

```
Result dosomething(char** str1, char* str){
    *str1=malloc(strlen(str2)+1); //followed by NULL check
    strcpy(*str1, str2);
```

calling as

```
result=dosomething(&input,output);
```

or change the function to return the newly allocated string, returning `NULL` to indicate an error

```
char* dosomething(char* str){
    char* str1=malloc(strlen(str2)+1); //followed by NULL check
    strcpy(str1, str2);
    ...
    return str1;
```

calling as

```
input=dosomething(output);
if (input==NULL) {
    // error
```

Comment: I've tried it, same result. but correct me if I'm wrong, but char* is a pointer by itself, so either way I'm passing a pointer and it should change, why pass a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @littlerunaway Because passing a pointer only can help changing the object that is pointed to by the pointer. A pointer is not magic, it's just a pointer. **Think.**

Comment: @littlerunaway a string is a `char*`.  This is passed by value to `dosomething`.  You can change the contents of the memory it points to inside `dosomething` but cannot change what memory it points to.  To change the memory it points to, you need to pass a pointer to the string i.e. a `char**`

Comment: but isn't this what I'm trying to do? change the object that is pointed to by the pointer?

Comment: Yes, its exactly what you're trying to do.  You can't do it pass passing a `char*` argument to `doSomething`.  You can do it in either of the ways outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass string by pointer to pointer

```
Result dosomething(char** str1, char* str){
    *str1=malloc(strlen(str2)+1); //followed by NULL check
    strcpy(*str1, str2);
```

and use as

```
result=dosomething(&input,output);
```

Since you need to modify the pointer's value so pass its address.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting tripped up because you're changing the value of the pointer you're passing inside the function.  For the sake of illustration replace your `char*` here with `int` to see what's going wrong:

```
Result dosomething_int(int a, int b) {
    a = 29;
    ...
}
```

Here `29` takes the place of your `malloc` call, which replaces the value of the `str1` pointer you passed with a new value.  Now use this function:

```
int output = 17;
int intput = 0;
result = dosomething_int(input,output);
```

Would you expect the value of `input` to to be 0 or 29 after this?  Probably you can answer this question easily -- the same thing is happening in the `char *` case.  You'll need to pass a pointer to your `char *` to solve it:

```
Result dosomething(char** str1, char * str2) {
    *str1 = malloc(...);
    ...
}
```